# How does Rocket know all those things about Lil Zé?

Tags: plot-explanation, city-of-god

In [City of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_God_(2002_film)) (2002), one thing I didn't understand was how the reporter named "Rocket" knows all the things about "Lil Zé".

For example, he knows Lil Zé killed Goose. Also, how does he knows about that boy whose father was killed by Knockout Ned?

Comment: stories. bragging. growing up in those neighbourhoods, anything you do, you brag about it. and seeing as how Ze wanted to be the top gangster, him spreading stories about the killings would further increase his fame. same with all the other characters. stories are told about them, and only the people who lived there would know, hence no-one from "outside" would know, unless told.

Comment: Goose was the Rocket's brother... so when his brother was killed he wanted to know who did this, this is an information that if he asked to someone that "worked" with Lil Zé, would know.

Answer (score 1):

It's because he grew up in the same neighborhood as Lil Zé. The reporter Rocket is the one with the camera and is also the one who takes the first picture of them

Comment: Yes i agree but how does he knows that lil ze killed goose,and also the story about the bank guy who killed by knockout ned?